# validate xml with same element multiple times

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to validate this xml file with a xsd file. How can I validate the next steps?

1. Number of times the item "atributo" appears.
2. "nombre" node has the same value in each element.
3. "valor" node has not empty value.

### xml file

```
<datos>
<elemento tipoelemento="CABECERA">
    <atributo>
        <nombre>VERSION</nombre>
        <valor>1.0</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>BRIGADA</nombre>
        <valor>JADSJL</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>BUZON</nombre>
        <valor>ASDKLFJKA</valor>
    </atributo>
</elemento>
</datos>
```

I try this but I don´t konw if that is possible.

### xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="datos">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="elemento">
                     <xs:alternative test="@tipoelemento = 'CABECERA'" type="cabecera"/>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="cabecera">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="atributo" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you have tried and where you have looked for information. The internet is full of online courses and tutorials about XML and XSD. You may not be able to find all the answers, but you should at least _try_.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, the internet can help you a lot with these questions. for example w3 schools is a good place to start. I'm not going to give you a full working example but will help you getting started.

an xsd is not a dynamic thing that can give you output like the occurs of an element list. the xsd is a contract where is stated that an element can occur 0 or more times or needs to be between values. this can be achieved by using the min and max occurs switch.

Same for your second question you can pre define that the element needs to hold fixed content but you cannot specify that the content of the first element should be equal to all the other occurs. To use fixed content you use the fixed switch.
If the content need to be fixed but there is more than one option you can define a simple type with an restriction and use enumerations to add the desired content.

As for the third question this is depending on what kind of type you assign to the element. but in general by adding facets to the element you can specify the minimal and maximal size of the content.

There are many other ways than the above to solve your problems, like the use of regular expressions. Investigate them as well.

I hope this helps you in the right direction and to solve your problem.